# Changing Email address through phpmailer

Tags: phpmailer

Can I change `<help.akunatch@gmail.com>` through phpmailer?

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can set the from address using the `From` property (and the name via the `FromName` property), or using the `setFrom` method to do both at once:

```
$mail->From = 'myotheraddress@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Akunatech support';
```

or:

```
$mail->setFrom('myotheraddress@example.com', 'Akunatech support');
```

That said, I can see you're sending through gmail, which does not allow you to use arbitrary from addresses (it will revert to your account address if you try), but you can configure aliases in gmail settings.

Comment: thanks for your reply @Synchro  but i want to change aliases name dynamically. Is that possible through phpmailer?

Comment: You can set a from address dynamically, but gmail will ignore it. If you can change gmail aliases dynamically (which I doubt), it would be via one of gmail's HTTP APIs, not via SMTP (and thus outside PHPMailer's control). I'd recommend sending via a service that gives you more control, for example by using your own mail server or a mail API like mailgun. I'd also query why you think you need to do this, as sending from arbitrary addresses will often result in SPF failures, spam filtering, and bounces.

Comment: <help.akunatch@gmail.com> should i hide this @Synchro

Comment: That's up to you. Having the real from address provided valuable information to be able to answer the question correctly, though if you're getting spammed at that address due to harvesting from SO, then it may be a good idea to edit it out, at least from the text of your question if not the image.